# How can I read a Garage Band file on a USB stick with my PC?

Tags: mac, pc, file, transfer

hey I have a garage band file on my USB. how can i transfer that file into a format i can listen or perhaps even better, edit, on my PC. Note that this is after I plug it into my PC not on the mac.

Comment: You can't open a GarageBand project on Windows. You have to export it to audio on Mac or iOS first.

Comment: Export the garageband file as an MP3 using your garageband software. Then upload it to the USB and you can then listen to it anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The right way to do this is open the project in GarageBand and export each track as its own audio file. Then you can import the audio files into a PC-based multichannel audio editor and continue working.

Failing that, though, notice that the GarageBand project is a folder, and inside the folder there is a “Media” folder that contains the individual audio clips that are used in the project. It may be enough for your purposes to import those into a PC-based multichannel audio editor, although you will lose all the edits that were made in GarageBand. Depending on how the project is structured, that may or may not matter to you.